# The method 'animateToPage' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, clone

I'm trying to clone Instagram and the Navigation Bar dos not navigate but it through me an error The method 'animateToPage' was called on null.

this is the code for it

```
 Scaffold  buildHomeScreen(){
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          TimeLinePage(),
          SearchPage(),
          UploadPage(),
          NotificationsPage(),
          ProfilePage(),

        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: whenPageChanges,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        currentIndex: getPageIndex,
        onTap: onTapChangePage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        activeColor: Colors.white,
        inactiveColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera, size: 37.0,)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person)),


        ],
      ),

    );
```

and those are the methods i use

```
 whenPageChanges(int pageIndex){
    setState(() {
      this.getPageIndex = pageIndex;
    });

  }
  onTapChangePage(int pageIndex){
    pageController.animateToPage(pageIndex, duration:Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
  }
```

Comment: Where did you initialized `pageController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the `pageController` is initialized in the right place? You also need to remember to cancel it in dispose.
Show me the part of the code where you create the controller.

Comment: yes i think so can u check that please 
` }
  void dispose(){
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();

  }`

Comment: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics is used to make it static right ?

Comment: @fareskhalid It will not allow the user to scroll, but you can programmatically control the scroll.

Comment: i tried to comment that NeverScrollableScrollPhysics and it works thx dude